Unable to suppress non-built-in warnings e.g. "CryptographyDeprecationWarning"
Question
How can I suppress non-built-in warnings using the python -W{action:message:category:module:line} option?
Environment
I am using an official Python-based Docker image python:3.7.9 with the following setup:
$ python -V
Python 3.7.9
$ pip list | grep -e redis -e cryptography
cryptography           44.0.0
redis                  4.5.1
types-redis            4.6.0.11

Background
When I run tests on an older Python project (Python==3.7.9), I get the following warning:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:1728: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.7 is no longer supported by the Python core team and support for it is deprecated in cryptography. A future release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.7.

This warning seems to originate from the cryptography package, which is imported indirectly via the redis package:
if sys.version_info[:2] == (3, 7):
    warnings.warn(
        "Python 3.7 is no longer supported by the Python core team "
        "and support for it is deprecated in cryptography. A future "
        "release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.7.",
        utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning,
        stacklevel=2,
    )

Source: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/main/src/cryptography/__init__.py
I know that upgrading Python is the best radical solution, but right now I want to suppress only this particular warning cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning to focus on testing other parts of the project. However, I don't know how to specify warnings that are not built-in by category.
To summarize my question, is there a way to correctly specify and suppress this non-built-in warning with a command line option - not by matching messages - but by specifying a warning category?
What I tried
Specifying a warning category name does not work.
For example:
$ pytest -Wignore::CryptographyDeprecationWarning
ERROR: while parsing the following warning configuration:

  ignore::CryptographyDeprecationWarning

This error occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1690, in parse_warning_filter
    category: Type[Warning] = _resolve_warning_category(category_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1729, in _resolve_warning_category
    cat = getattr(m, klass)
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'CryptographyDeprecationWarning'

Note: The -W option passed to pytest has the same behavior as if you had given it directly to Python.
Using the full module path fails to suppress the warning:
$ pytest -Wignore::cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning
============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.9, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /app, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: mock-3.10.0
collected 192 items                                                                                              

... # test contents

================================================ warnings summary ================================================
../usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:1728
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:1728: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.7 is no longer supported by the Python core team and support for it is deprecated in cryptography. A future release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.7.
    m = __import__(module, None, None, [klass])

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
========================================= 192 passed, 1 warning in 5.20s =========================================

On the other hand, filtering by the message text works as expected:
$ pytest -W ignore:'Python 3.7 is no longer supported by the Python core team and support for it is deprecated in cryptography. A future release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.7.'
=========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.9, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /app/proj, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: mock-3.10.0, anyio-3.7.1
collected 6 items                                                                                                                                                                                         

... # test contents 

============================================================================================ 6 passed in 0.04s ============================================================================================


This issue is the same when configuring filterwarnings in pytest.ini:
[pytest]  
# filterwarnings = ignore::CryptographyDeprecationWarning # Error
# filterwarnings = ignore::cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning # Does not suppress
filterwarnings = ignore:Python 3.7 is no longer supported by the Python core team and support for it is deprecated in cryptography. A future release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.7. # Works

Furthermore, the same is true if the option is given directly to Python.
$ python -Wignore::CryptographyDeprecationWarning -m pytest
# => Invalid -W option ignored: unknown warning category: 'CryptographyDeprecationWarning'
# ... Tests run with options ignored.
$ python -Wignore::cryptography.utils.CryptographyDeprecationWarning -m pytest # ignored this option
# => Invalid -W option ignored: invalid module name: 'cryptography.utils'
# ... Tests run with options ignored.

$ python -W'ignore:Python 3.7 is no longer supported by the Python core team and support for it is deprecated in cryptography. A future release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.7.' -m pytest 
# ... tests run with correctly suppressed CyptographyDeprecationWarning

I found that CryptographyDeprecationWarning extends from UserWarning, so I tried as follows, but it still did not work.
$ pytest -Wignore::UserWarning:cryptography.utils
# or
$ python -Wignore::UserWarning:cryptography.utils -m pytest

Notice: I want to do a temporary check, so I want to achieve this with a command line option without changing the code as much as possible.

This question is similar to: How to disable Python warnings?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The link suggests a way to suppress built-in warnings like DeprecationWarning or UserWarning, but what I want to know is how to suppress non-built-in warnings by category specification. As I mentioned multiple times in my post, the same approach used for built-in warnings does not work and then I am asking about non-built-in warnings. Is there something specific I might be overlooking?

i don't know which link you're talking about. the first answer of the question i linked provides two ways of disabling any warning

I am talking about the link you provided, "How to disable Python warnings?", and this Q&A does not solve my problem. Please check again what I summarized at the end of the Background section, the point is to use the arguments given to the command line option "-W" and to suppress specific non-built-in warnings, not indiscriminately. The provided Q&A mentions changing the code itself, suppressing all warnings, or only built-in warnings, which is not what I want.
In fact, the warning in my question occurs during the process of importing modules, so it is hard to suppress them in code.

command line works the same way as warning.filterwarnings: the easiest is to target line number -Wignore::::1728 should work

That is, your answer is that “it is impossible to specify non-built-in warnings at the category level due to the python specification, and the only way is to specify them at other levels, such as line numbers”? Or did you simply provide an ad hoc solution? I know it works by filtering at the message level, so I'd like to wait for other responses if there might be a potential fundamental solution.

ad hoc yes. but i think this one is good -Wignore::UserWarning:cryptography

Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and unfortunately it did not work, similar to -Wignore::UserWarning:cryptography.utils (which generates the same warning as without the option).
